# Using newcommand and gnuplot to plot sums of parametric functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I want to add (or subtract) a bunch of parametric plots together, something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myPlota}[1]{
    (#1>0?(t<#1?0:1):(t<-#1?-1:0))
}
\newcommand{\myPlotb}[1]{
    (#1>0?(t<#1?1:2):(t<-#1?-2:-3))
}
\newcommand{\myGraph}[3]{
    \draw [domain=#1:#2] plot[parametric,] function{t,#3};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \myGraph{-1}{4}{\myPlotb{2}-\myPlota{1}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the right answer if I use either

```
\myGraph{-1}{4}{\myPlotb{2}-\myPlota{1}}
```

or

```
\myGraph{-1}{4}{0-\myPlota{1}+\myPlotb{2}}
```

But, if I remove the zero, that is, I simply use

```
\myGraph{-1}{4}{-\myPlota{1}+\myPlotb{2}}
```

then the negative sign is ignored by `gnuplot` and I get the wrong answer. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in Gnuplot. I would expect `0-(1?5:42)` and `-(1?5:42)` both to evaluate to `-5` but it does not in gnuplot:

`gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 2`

```
gnuplot> plot[-1:1] [-10:10] 0-(1?5:42) , -(1?5:42)
```

[image: Gnuplot output window with 5 and -5 graph]

**Edit:** Simpler with the `print` function in gnuplot

```
gnuplot> print 0-(1?5:42)
-5
gnuplot> print -(1?5:42)
5
gnuplot>
```

**Edit:**

I do not know the reason to use Gnuplot for these very simple calculations, so here is a TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myPlota}[1]{
    (#1>0?(\t<#1?0:1):(\t<-#1?-1:0))
}
\newcommand{\myPlotb}[1]{
    (#1>0?(\t<#1?1:2):(\t<-#1?-2:-3))
}
\newcommand{\myGraph}[3]{
    \draw [domain=#1:#2] plot[variable=\t] (\t,{#3});
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\myGraph{-1}{4}{0-\myPlota{1}+\myPlotb{2}}
\begin{scope}[yshift=2 cm]
\myGraph{-1}{4}{-\myPlota{1}+\myPlotb{2}}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two of the same line plot with dip in the middle]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I simplified the calculations for the sake of the MWE. I am trying to add functionality to the `bodegraph` package, which is written entirely using `gnuplot`. I have added all that I want to and fixed all the bugs, other than this one issue. I suppose I will just have to instruct users to use the `0-...` version until the bug is fixed in `gnuplot`. It should be simple enough to rewrite the whole package in vanilla `TikZ`, I suppose, all it needs is `log10`, `exp`, and some trigonometric functions. Just a matter of finding time....

Comment: [Created a ticket] (https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2468/), hopefully it gets fixed in `gnuplot`.